# Which is easier to write drivers for? Windows or LInux?

Tags: windows, linux, driver

I am trying to learn a little about driver development and my question is, which OS has an easier API to develop drivers with? Windows or Linux?

Remember that I am new to this.

Thanks

Comment: This is a subjective question. Depends on your previous experience. One guy might be more comfortable with Windows or Linux. In general, however, having the source code to the kernel is helpful when you develop Linux drivers.

Comment: Are you new to Windows or new to Linux? Or perhaps you're new to writing *any* kind of OS driver? If the latter, then you're in for a lot of learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing this for learning (I guess its your case), then go for Linux, you will have a more general ideal on how an OS works, you will interact with low level implementation straight to the core.

If you are just writing a driver for a device, I recommend using Visual Studio under Windows, it has a lot of features that will really help on your devel.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure you'll get lots of Windows vs Linux war here, unfortunately.

On Windows, you'll get pretty good development tools, with some awkward stuff, but that you can get along with easily. API is documented provided you have access to a Windows Developer account. Remote debugging is supported and it helps a lot for these kernel stuff that are triggering BSOD so quickly.

On Linux, you'll need to get your hands more dirty. *Rubini's "Linux Device Drivers"* is a **very good** starting point. Openness will bring you more flexibility, and more understanding of what is happening.

Comment: The Linux book can be found online at http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/. You might also be interested in _Linux Kernel in a Nutshell_ http://www.kroah.com/lkn/. Maybe also the Linux from Scratch project http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/.

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux) might be helpful.

It is about writing a simple device driver for linux.

Answer (score 1):

My personal idea is Linux. You can see the entire code other than an API.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows is good.
Because it has a rich set of API's which is easier to use